# VSCode Extension - works using F5 debug, fails after copying to extensions folder

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I created a new extension using the examples provided on-line. Everything is great and it all works perfectly using the F5 debug mode. No errors.

I copied the extension to the extensions folder and can see the right-click menus that the extension adds to VScode just fine, but when I run the menu command I get nothing... No errors in any consoles, just tumbleweed...

Other extensions I download are working just fine. Only the copied one fails to run.

Am I missing something, some extra config ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to check runtime errors after your extension has been installed use the Developer Tools (Help -> Toggle Developer Tools). After all vscode (based on Electron) is a web application and you can debug it like you would in a web browser.

Comment: Awesome. Hadn't realized that, found the issue and fixed. Thanks Mike !